# Fatal error database <dbname> does not exists postgresql

Tags: windows, postgresql

1. Everything was fine until windows asked for launch repair at startup.
2. When windows finished repair then postgres producing error while try to connect with it
   "Fatal error database postgres does not exists"

even i have tried reinstalling.
and data directory checks for base folder where database files are kept (everything looks fine there)
Does anyone have idea why this is happening?.

Comment: So what do you see when you run `\l` in `psql`?

Comment: when i open psql ,it prompts for password. after entering right password psql window closed automatically due to above error

Comment: Then first start `cmd.exe` then from within the command line run `psql -d template1` if you still get an error, you can at least read it. But you probably need to delete your data directory, run `initdb` to create a new one, then restore your backup.

Comment: Thanks ..i will try immediately and let u know..

Comment: how to restore backup after initdb ?

Comment: i have backup in the form of data directory only..